# recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT occurs when trying to upload a video

Tags: java, android, video, upload, timeout

I need to upload Videos from Application to our Server. A strange thing is happening when i am trying to upload a Video taken from Device's Camera. It's working fine for some Videos which was not taken from Camera. For Camera Videos it's just trying to connect to server and after a  time it's showing following error. Does anybody have ever faced of such kind of problem. Please share with me if any Solution for this. Thanks in advance. here below is Error and followed by my code.

java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

```
public String uploadPostCameraVideoPic() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    String responseString = null;
    String urlServer;

    urlServer = SERVERContants.URL ;


    String path = (String) mData.get(0);

    File f = new File(path);

    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,
            SERVERContants.TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams,
            SERVERContants.TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

    try {
        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(urlServer);
        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

        String postType = dc.getPostType(path);

        entity.addPart("name", new StringBody("videos"));
        entity.addPart("functionName", new StringBody("uploadFileAndriod"));
        entity.addPart("filename", new StringBody(path));
        entity.addPart(postType, new FileBody(f));

        httpost.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response;
        response = httpclient.execute(httpost);

        System.out.println("the Resposne======" + response);
        responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        System.out.println("the responseString======" + responseString);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("the Exception occurs 1===== " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("the Exception occurs 2===== " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return responseString;
}
```

Comment: Are the files from the camera larger? If so, see if you can increase the timeout period.

Comment: Also setConnectionTimeout and setSoTimeOut are deprecated in 4.3 if that's what you are using. See the docs http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/params/HttpConnectionParams.html I'm not saying that's waht is causing your error